# Jquery tabify with form (Multiple Instances problem ?)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery tabify with 4 tabs and each content same form calling via ajax.(assume form.php)
1st tab everything works fine with the form.
2nd,3rd and 4th tab failed to get input type="text" value

tabify field with (4 tabs here actually I make it short as the code is long):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#general_information_tab').tabify();

});

function recp(refer,id,plan){
    if(plan == 0)
    {
    $('.stgcontent').load('stage/stage_procedure1.php?plan_id=' + id + '&T_REFERID=' + refer );
    }else{
    $('.stgcontent').load('stage/new_taskstg.php?plan_id=' + id + '&T_ID=' + refer);
    }

    <div id="general_tab_content">
             <ul id="general_information_tab" class="general_information_tab">
                <li class="active"><a href="#one" onClick="recp('1','<?php echo $plan_id; ?>','0')" >Immediate Response Steps</a></li>
<div id="one" class="content_gi">
            <div class="stg1">

            <a href="#" onClick="recp('1','<?php echo $plan_id; ?>','1')" class="stg1"><img src="images/task/add.ico" height="10px" width="10px" /> &nbsp; Add Task</a>
            <div class="stgcontent">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    recp('1','<?php echo $plan_id; ?>','0');
            </script>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

in new_taskstg.php

```
$(function(){
$(".newTaskSubmitBtn").click(function(){
var T_CONTENT = $(".task_name").val();
var T_REFERID = $(".refer").val();
var SAVE_PLAN = $(".plan").val();
var V_ID = $(".vendor").val();

var dataString='T_CONTENT=' + T_CONTENT + '&T_REFERID=' + T_REFERID + '&SAVE_PLAN=' + SAVE_PLAN + '&V_ID=' + V_ID;

alert(T_CONTENT + T_REFERID + SAVE_PLAN + V_ID);
if(T_CONTENT=='' || T_REFERID=='' || SAVE_PLAN=='' || V_ID=='')
{
    //ERROR MESSAGE
    $(".fail").show();
    $(".success").hide();
}
else
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "stage/insert.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data){
            //SUCCESS MESSAGE
            $(".success").show();
            $(".fail").hide();
        }
        });

}
return false;

});
});
```

form field code:

```
<input type="text" name="task_name" class="form_input task_name" />
```

**TEST I DID :**

As above var T_CONTENT = $(".task_name").val(); and prompt like this alert(T_CONTENT); what it shows on 1st tab it able to capture it while the 2nd 3rd and 4th tab failed...

*Was suspecting multiple instances problem...*

Comment: I'm not very familiar with tabify, but generally it's a bad idea to call `.val()` when you have applied it as a class. If it's the only instance, give it an ID. So on the 2nd and third tab, does the call fail?

Comment: John as stated title Multiple instance~ It was 4 tab there just I make shortcut as the code is long tho... Well call doesn't fail just that input text field failed ...

Comment: Try alerting `$(".task_name").length` on all tabs after 1 to see if the element is available. If you set up a demo on jsfiddle we could have a look

Comment: tried alert($(".task_name").length); result : 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. Mian point is to avoid from multiple instances since tabify couldn't differentiate which tab the form is and it takes 4 tabs together. So to solve my case I just use unique id in 4 forms.